# Error - 52162 - Credentials do not belong to used account - Twilio Configuration

Tags: twilio

I am trying to call using Twilio Client in Twilio Console getting the below
Error - 52162
Credentials do not belong to used account

description "Unauthorized: Credential CR62376047c277240bf110833a73b0f09e does not belong to Account ACe60123e1458ba461d6a1951aeca761e1"

I am using the push credential which I created, but for some reason the app keeps using an old one that isn't in my account.

This "CR62376047c277240bf110833a73b0f09e" is not my push credential. I have changed the environment variable with my push credential SID and still the app seems to be using this one from somewhere.

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: “*How do I fix this?*” We can’t possibly answer this question without seeing your code - please edit your question to include it as a [mre]. See also: [ask]

Comment: How are you setting the environment variable?

Comment: Using SETX and also checking in System/User Variables and checking in .env file